# R Shiny app error - mysql con - Shiny Server

Tags: r, azure, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny Server running in Ubuntu VM in Azure (the sample apps work fine - http://ip:3838/sample-apps/hello/).

When I copy my Shiny app(a folder "myapp" with server.R and ui.R files) in /srv/shiny-server/ and access http://ip:3838/myapp/, I get an error message: `ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.` (nothing related to this error in shiny server log)

In server.R I have 2 sql queries fetching data from a mysql db. (could that be a problem? - when I use RStudio locally, on my computer, and run the queries from a different file to create the needed dataframes, I can run the Shiny app succesfully)

here's a part of my server.R and ui.R files:

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
library(ggplot2)
#library(ggiraph)
library(lubridate)

##Connect to Redmine db
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user = '#',
                 password = '#',
                 host = '#',
                 dbname='#')

tickets<-dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from table")
issues_speed_unique<-unique(na.omit(dbGetQuery(con,"Select * from table2")))
dbDisconnect (con) 

some aggregations....

shinyServer(
  function(input,output){
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#library(ggiraph)
#library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @F.Santiago if I remember correctly, it was a problem with Azure not being able to connect to our databases yet...It was matter of setting up some proper channels of communication between Azure and outside database (but I don't know how that communication was setup). Check first in the R terminal on Azure, if u can connect and fetch some data (that's how I discovered that was a connection problem)

Comment: @F.Santiago AAA, and very important, for me it only worked by putting the code in one file app.R, and write the _server_ logic first and than the _ui_ (because I was using some dynamic data in the ui, so first it had to be processed by the server)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @adlisval. 
In my case, it was a missing library, but since I was using a docker container to run the server that was not outputing .R logs, I could not get details on the issue.
As soon as I correctly configured the logging, it was clear.